# Need someone to explain my situation about @Transactional (spring)

Tags: spring-transactions

I have controller call a service_A, and service_A call service_B, in service_B have 3 method.

A method_A call method_B and method_C in order.

I want to rollback when method_B occur an exception, I tried many ways.

1. Add @Transactional on method_B, but not rollback
2. Add @Transactional on method_A, rollback, but not commit before method_C (method_C need to use data commited)
3. Add @Transactional(with REQUIRED_NEW) on method_A, method_B result as 1, 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `PlatformTransactionManager` and `TransactionTemplate` for manual transaction (remove `@Transactional`).